# Audit fields for AppEngine entities

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

Looking for suggestions for an efficient way to maintain basic audit fields for entities in AppEngine for Java (via objectify). The @PrePersist attribute looks like a good option for various date fields (dateCreated, dateModified, dateDeleted) but I'm also looking to store the ID of the user who created, modified, deleted the entity as well. Is this best left to the data access layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to store records with more than just the dates you mention you probably want to create an audit object and use @Embed to store it inside of the objects you're auditing. Then use @PrePersist to update this object. That will give you a consistent audit framework across objects.

Comment: If I use \@PrePersist, how do I get hold of the user ID? The only way we have to access it is through a user retrieval service which grabs it from the HttpSession. Is it common practice to inject some sort of service into domain entities to get this information?

Comment: Yes. You can either get it from the session or read it from a cookie. That totally depends on your application. Generally the DAO layer of your application would have a method like doUpdate(User, Entity)

Comment: We have a DAO layer but I'm not sure I like the idea of having to pass in the user to every doUpdate method. Shouldn't the DAO layer intrinsically know how to do this?

Comment: If you write it that way... But it has to get the user from somewhere, in this case an httpsession or a variable you pass in. You could attach the session with the user to a thread local object and get it that way if you like but that's up to you to manage.

Comment: Don't forget, "user" is something that you invent. Objectify has no notion of "user" and objectify 4 doesn't even have a dao object. So to say "shouldn't the dao layer intrinsically know how to do this" is really flawed.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO `@PrePersist` is an ok place to perform this.

You also might want to use [objectify's polymorphism](http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/IntroductionToObjectify#Polymorphism) - this way you could have a base class containing all audit fields and perform saving. Than all classes needing audit would just extend this base class.